# Hetzner Vlan connectivity between VMs inside dedicated server connected on Vswitch

Tags: virtualization, vlan, hetzner

I have multiple dedicated server with hetzner and connected to one vSwitch. I can connecte the dedicated servers on vlan using vswitch. But I am struggling to connect virtual machine inside dedicated servers to connect to VLAN. so vm can also connect on vlan (private ) to other dedicated servers or VM on another dedicated servers. Just for info I am using virtulizor for Virtualization and routed network for VM (addtional ips ). Please suggest or let me know if need any other info.

Thanks

Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this working. We need to setup vlan same on VM as we do on dedicated server(using hetzner guide). Issue was that on main host I was creating VLAN using physical interface which we should do with bridge interface we use for Virtualization. Else it will change routing for VLAN subnet.